# How to toggle the jquery blind effect(as default) without the select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to show the object when button clicked with blind effect but without showing up the select list. here is the link of [code](https://jqueryui.com/toggle/).
thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need like this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Effects - Toggle Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
  .toggler {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #button {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #effect {
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 0.4em;
  }
  #effect h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();
 
      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};
      // some effects have required parameters
      if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
        options = { percent: 0 };
      } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
        options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
      }
 
      // run the effect
      $( "#effect" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 500 );
    };
 runEffect();
    // set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Toggle</h3>
    <p>
      Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
 
<select name="effects" id="effectTypes" style="display:none;">
  <option value="blind">Blind</option>
</select>
 
<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go : 
https://jsfiddle.net/54z8vLLb/

```
var selectedEffect = "blind";
```

Just remove the select markup from HTML and set the default value to "blind" in javascript function.